# AWS STS: GetFederationToken works locally, but fails from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, sts

I'm trying to call generate a temporary token via STS, using the `aws-sdk` (Typescript). This is the code which tries to obtain the token.

```js
export async function handler() {
  const token = await sts
    .getFederationToken({
      DurationSeconds: 7200,
      Name: "test",
      Policy: JSON.stringify({
        Version: "2012-10-17",
        Statement: {
          Effect: "Allow",
          Action: "ses:*",
          Resource: "*",
        },
      }),
    })
    .promise();
}
```

Executing it locally works. Deploying it to a Lambda and running it yields the following error:

```
{
  "errorType": "AccessDenied",
  "errorMessage": "Cannot call GetFederationToken with session credentials",
  "trace": [
    "AccessDenied: Cannot call GetFederationToken with session credentials",
    "    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:50:29)",
    "    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
    "    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
    "    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)",
    "    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
    "    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
    "    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
    "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
    "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:12)",
    "    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)"
  ]
}
```

I am fairly certain the function has all the rights that are necessary (`sts:*`, `ses:*`, ...). Do Lambdas generally run in a context where `getFederationToken` is not permitted?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem.... I understand that Lambda get's it's role via AssumeRole, which if we look at the [STS API Comparison](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_request.html#stsapi_comparison) it says

> Cannot call GetFederationToken or GetSessionToken.

And if we continue to look it appears no such api is able to call those API's (Being an STS operation)

The only workaround I can figure is to create an IAM user, and use it's API keys directly (Stored securely, perhaps in Secrets Manager)